# que debo modificar ya que me dice que esta fuera de rango en python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import csv


class Contact:


    def __init__(self, name, phone, email):
        self.name = name
        self.phone = phone
        self.email = email


class Agenda:

    def __init__(self):
        self._contacts = []

    def add(self, name, phone, email):
        contact = Contact(name, phone, email)
        self._contacts.append(contact)
        self._save()

    def visualizar(self,):
        for contact in self._contacts:
            self._print_contacto(contact)

    def borrar(self, name):
        for idx, contact in enumerate(self._contacts):
            if contact.name.lower() == name.lower():
                del self._contacts[idx]
                self._save()
                break

    def buscar(self, name):
        for contact in self._contacts:
            if contact.name.lower() == name.lower():
                self._print_contacto(contact)
                break
        else:
            self._not_found()

    def _save(self):
        with open('contacts.csv', 'w') as f:
            writer = csv.writer(f)
            writer.writerow( ('name', 'phone', 'email') )

            for contact in self._contacts:
                writer.writerow( (contact.name, contact.phone, contact.email) )


    def _print_contacto(self, contact):
        print('--- * --- * --- * --- * --- *--- *---')
        print('Nombre: {}'.format(contact.name))
        print('telefono: {}'.format(contact.phone))
        print('Email: {}'.format(contact.email))
        print('--- * --- * --- * --- * --- *--- *---')

    def _not_found(self):
        print('++++++++++++++')
        print('¡No encontrado!')
        print('+++++++++++++++++')

def run():

    libro_agenda = Agenda()

    with open('contacts.csv', 'r') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        for idx, row in enumerate(reader):
            if idx == 0:
                continue

            libro_agenda.add(row[0], row[1], row[2])


    while True:
        command = str(input('''
                ¿Que deseas hacer?

                [a]ñadir contacto
                [ac]tualizar contacto
                [b]uscar contacto
                [e]liminar contacto
                [l]istar contacto
                [s]alir
            '''))

        if command == 'a':
            name = str(input('Escribe el numero del contacto: '))
            phone = str(input('escribe el telefono de contacto: '))
            email = str(input('escribe el email del contacto: '))

            libro_agenda.add(name, phone, email)

        elif command == 'ac':
            pass

        elif command == 'b':
            name = str(input('Escribe el nombre del contacto: '))

            libro_agenda.buscar(name)

        elif command == 'e':
            name = str(input('Escribe el nombre del contacto: '))

            libro_agenda.borrar(name)


        elif command == 'l':

            libro_agenda.visualizar()

        elif command == 's':
            break
        else:
            print('comando no encontrado')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('B I E N V E N I D O  A  T U  L I S T A   D E  C O N T A C T O S')
    run()
```

y me sale el siguiente error:

```
B I E N V E N I D O  A  T U  L I S T A   D E  C O N T A C T O S
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Termporal\contactos.py", line 122, in <module>
    run()
  File "C:\Termporal\contactos.py", line 75, in run
    libro_agenda.add(row[0], row[1], row[2])
IndexError: list index out of range
[Finished in 0.422s]

**
```

Comment: podrias explicar que haces para que surja ese error, lee [ask], pasa el [tour] y mejora tu pregunta

Comment: Lo que indica el error es que una de las filas del csv no tiene 3 items como supones. Imprime row en el ciclo antes de la llamada a `libro_agenda.add(row[0], row[1], row[2])` para detectar que está pasando. Si no agregas el csv o parte de el que reproduzca el problema va a ser difícil ayudarte.  Por cierto, para eliminar la primera fila no uses un condicional, es ineficiente, simplemente haz `next(reader)` antes del `for`, te ahorras el condicional y `enumerate`..

Comment: quería leer el arcivo csv. "el cual esta creado" y que solo me llamara los 3 columnas para el momento de volver a ejecutar el programa; son cursos de programación que estoy aprendiendo gracias!!, cuando tenga tiempo pasare por el manual de la pagina para saber preguntar mejor.

Comment: lionronal el problema está precisamente en la lectura del csv como comento, o el archivo no es un csv  válido, o se está parseando mal (separador incorrecto por ejemplo) o hay una línea que no tiene las tres columnas que debería tener (linea en blanco por ejemplo).

Comment: eyllanesc, si entiendo lo que me dices, por eso revise el archivo csv, y si tiene solo tres columnas; "name,phone,email", para que cuando agregue los contactos, queden guardados al momento de iniciar nuevamente el programa y así llamarlos de vuelta;

Comment: @lionronald si quieres una respuesta rápida y de calidad tu pregunta debe ser de calidad, desde mi punto de vista has lanzado código y dices no me funciona, y en mi cabeza digo ¿que no le funcione?, he intentado ejecutar tu codigo y al no tener un .csv he creado uno vacio, y aun asi me es  dificil reproducir tu problema ¿como puedo reproducir su error?. Entenderás que no estamos en tu cabeza, no sé lo que intentas ;)

Comment: @lionronald una posibilidad es que cuando creas inicialmente tu csv estés usando Windows y el editor de texto con el que lo creas use  `\r\n` como fin de línea.... Usa `with open('contacts.csv', 'r', newline='') as f:` para abrir el archivo (lo mismo para cuando escribes en el). Si haces lo que te digo arriba, `print(row)` justo antes de la linea del error te darás cuenta del error, estoy casi seguro que te imprime una tupla vacía (línea vacía) justo antes de la excepción.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@lionronald
Tu codigo funciona si tu archivo esta vacio. Pude crear, buscar y listar contactos. Sin tener el archivo csv que estas usando no podemos replicar el error. Talvez lo modificaste por error. Mueve tu archivo, y crea un "contacts.csv" vacio y agrega algunos contactos. Luego de eso compara los 2 archivos csv. Tengo la impression que el archivo que genera error fue creado con una version anterior de tu codigo.

AH! si estas tratando de leer un csv creado por otro programa, este tambien puede ser el problema.

Suerte, R6

```
                ¿Que deseas hacer?

                [a]ñadir contacto
                [ac]tualizar contacto
                [b]uscar contacto
                [e]liminar contacto
                [l]istar contacto
                [s]alir
            b
Escribe el nombre del contacto: rolando
--- * --- * --- * --- * --- *--- *---
Nombre: rolando
telefono: 1111111111
Email: rmondragon@gmail.com
--- * --- * --- * --- * --- *--- *---

                ¿Que deseas hacer?

                [a]ñadir contacto
                [ac]tualizar contacto
                [b]uscar contacto
                [e]liminar contacto
                [l]istar contacto
                [s]alir
            a
Escribe el numero del contacto: test
escribe el telefono de contacto: 3333333333
escribe el email del contacto: mry@yahoo.com

                ¿Que deseas hacer?

                [a]ñadir contacto
                [ac]tualizar contacto
                [b]uscar contacto
                [e]liminar contacto
                [l]istar contacto
                [s]alir
            l
--- * --- * --- * --- * --- *--- *---
Nombre: rolando
telefono: 1111111111
Email: rmondragon@gmail.com
--- * --- * --- * --- * --- *--- *---
--- * --- * --- * --- * --- *--- *---
Nombre: mrx
telefono: 2222222222
Email: x@hotmail.com
--- * --- * --- * --- * --- *--- *---
--- * --- * --- * --- * --- *--- *---
Nombre: test
telefono: 3333333333
Email: mry@yahoo.com
```

Comment: gracias!!, intentare nuevamente

Comment: al momentos de ejecutar el programa y añadir los contactos se crea el siguiente archivo csv;   con tres columnas: name , phone, emeail, en la cuales en cada una  van los datos de los contactos añadidos, lo que se quiere llegar hacer; es que al iniciar nuevamente el programa se ejecute con normalidad y al consultar los contactos aparezcan nuevamente,

Comment: @lionronald como te dije, al inicio el archivo estaba vacio, y agregue 3 contactos. termine el programa y lo inicie otra vez. 0 problemas. Agregue uno mas, liste,  y busque.. todo bien. No pude replicar tu error.  dime tus contactos tienen algun caracter extrano? ese podria ser el problema.

Comment: entonces si funciona, pero a mi no me deja iniciarlo con normalidad, no se cual sera el problema, definitivamente es en mi configuracion de atom?

Comment: si funciona. el editor? no uso atom. uso pycharm, pero para verificar lo ejecute en vscode, tambien funciona sin problemas... ah! yo borre la primera linea **# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-** pues me parecio innecesaria. estas seguro q estas usando python3?  ese tambien podria ser otro factor. asegurate q atom este bien configurado. Suerte

Comment: ps. 1 mas!!! yo estoy en Mac, no en Windows.. puede ser el character de fin de linea. Tengo q pensar q el modulo CSV tiene soporte para LF y CRLF. **Mira las notas  en la documentacion Dialect.lineterminator: Note The reader is hard-coded to recognise either '\r' or '\n' as end-of-line, and ignores lineterminator. This behavior may change in the future.** . https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/csv.html?highlight=csv#module-contents

Comment: dale gracias hermano, y si es python3, y ya comprobe con un amigo y tiene una mac y si le funciono sin problema y otro que tiene windows le da el mismo error, gracias de antemano